# How do you measure the level of improvements your website and dev team are doing?

Tags: statistics

I am looking for ways to measure and prove that our team is improving, but I can't just blankly state that, I need ways to prove it.

For example we are using coldfusion 8 and sql server 2005, and I can easily prove that the number of error's each day, week is getting less and less.

But what other figures, can i use to show what areas as a team, and programmer's of a site, that we need to either improve upon, or that we are making good progress on.

I am just a part time programmer, but I have far more programming experience, then my manager or the lead programmer.

So i want to help us identify and focus on areas we can improve upon, and ways to pay ourself on the back, for things we do good at.

Thank You...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a tip: Be careful with trying to improve you departments work if you are not one of the leaders. It's a good intention but be diplomatic.

Good ways to improve your output are code reviews. It worth much to have a group looking at code and share ideas to improve.

Another way is pair programming. In my opinion it doesn't have to be too often, but it is really helpful.

Third, do some occasional self education days where teams do some research on new technologies and stuff like this.

Hope this helps, Flo

Comment: Yes it does. I lead a friday training session, it's just hard to get other people interested. I just want to help, and I am not expecting me, to be the only presenter. So just looking for other ways...to help improve our team.

Comment: A diplomatic trick is to be "active passive" ask other people if **they** know some cool things that **you** should know. Help them into the driver seat to take a joint improvement journey. Just saying "I make you learn..." annoys people who do their job since years.

Comment: Your right, i have zero desire to force people, i just want to contribute to helping us be better.